# Can i test an ecommerce application on my local server

Tags: php, e-commerce

Am developing a web application that will enable my clients to buy some products from the site.
it is a php application.
I want to know how to add ecommerce ability to the site.
am new to ecommerce applications have not done one before

Comment: This question is far too broad in scope.

Comment: the biggest question is who you are using for the payment processing - charging the credit card. that is the most complicated task because you have to interact with a separate server that has its own programming requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @JohnRix, but to help you out, here are a couple (of the many) things you should consider, and then add them to your question to improve it:

What e-commerce platform would you like to use? Or would you code the e-commerce logic yourself in PHP? Some e-commerce apps are hosted, meaning you test on their test server (if they have one), and some use a library that you would add to your code base (meaning you test on your usual test server).

What payment processing method would you use to accept payments? Most have a separate test server that you can use to test against, and then you need to make sure you use their production server's URL in your code when you move to production.

Based on your tags, it looks like you want to use PHP, so look for e-commerce platforms or payment processors who have a good PHP library.

One thing I usually do in order to make it easy to move code from a test server to production is set Apache's APPLICATION_ENV in my apache config or .htaccess. Then you can write your code like this:

```
if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'test') {
    //Do something specific to the test env, for example use the test payment server:
    $payment_server = 'http://test-url';
} else if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'production') {
    //Do something specific to the production env...
}
```